# Plotting map - time to arrive - between 2 points

Tags: php, xml, time, direction, readxml

I have an xml file, generated with the distance and time data of an api request.
How to read this xml? I need to show only the time in an html or php.
Do you know the way?

Comment: is there any more information?you can add to your Question

Comment: Can you post sample data? Also, if you have any code you have tried please post that as well.